# C++: pass reference as parameter but that function doesn't accept reference as parameter

Tags: c++

I have this code snippet from [here](http://lspd.mackenzie.br/marathon/current/string.zip). Pls have a look at the file `spec.cc`.

```
Eval parse_recursive_descent (Grammar g, SymbolString input) {
    return
        parse_recursive_descent
            (g, Stack (SymbolString {g.start}, input, Path ())) ;
}

// MAIN ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main () {
    Input in = read_input (std::cin) ;
    Eval  ev = parse_recursive_descent (grammar (in), string (in)) ;
    print (make_output_string (derivations (ev), accept (ev))) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

The prototype of function `grammar` is: `Grammar& grammar (Input& in) ;`. So it returns a reference.

But `parse_recursive_descent` doesn't have the `g` parameter as reference. The question is: the `g` in function `parse_recursive_descent` is a reference or a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Eval parse_recursive_descent(Grammar g, SymbolString input)
```

`g` is a **value** of type `Grammar`. You know that because that's what the declaration says.

When you call the function, if the type that's passed doesn't exactly match the type that the function is expecting, the compiler generates code to make them match. So in the call

```
parse_recursive_descent(grammar(in), string(in));
```

the compiler converts the reference returned by `grammar(in)` into an object of type `Grammar` and passes that to `parse_recursive_descent`. To make the object it sets aside space for an object of type `Grammar` and uses the copy constructor, passing the reference that `grammar(in)` returns. You could do something similar like this:

```
Grammar temp(grammar(in));
parse_recursive_descent(temp, string(in));
```

The only difference if you do it that way is that you would have a **named object** (`temp`) instead of the (unnamed) temporary object that the compiler creates in your actual code.

Answer (score 3):

It's a value, copy-constructed from the reference you pass as argument.

The general idea is that all the parameters of a function are variables (of the specified type) local to the function. When you pass an argument, it is used as the initializer to construct the corresponding parameter.

Answer (score 1):

**Its a basic thing that you can assign a reference to a variable of the same type like:**

```
int i = 10;
int& j = i;
int k = j;//here j is a reference and value from j is copied to k
```

Here, as you said function `grammar` returns a reference of type `Grammar`. Now this returned value is sent to function `parse_recursive_descent` as an argument (to `Grammar g`). So it is as simple as assigning a variable of type `Grammar` to `g`.

```
Grammar g = variable of type Grammar; //this is a value copy
```

So, `g` is simply a value not a reference.

*Copy happens in copy constructor of `Grammar` class.